# can I clone a td as a th or clone props?

Tags: reactjs

```
          <table className={classes.deviceTable + ' deviceTable'}>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            {tickets.map(t => {
                    let header = true

                    return ITicketKeys.map(k =>{
                        let isMockHeader = !!header;
                        let cls = isMockHeader? classes.th : undefined;
                        header = false;

                        // would like these in the case of being a mock header, to be th instead of td
                        let t1 = <td key={k as string} className={cls}>{humanize(k as string)}</td>
                        let t2 = <td key={k + 'v'} className={cls}>{t[k]}</td>
                        return (
                        <tr key={k as string}>
                        </tr>);
                    });
            })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

can I either clone the elements' props onto `th` elements, or can I build a `props` object that I could conditionally apply to `<td ...props>` or `<th ...props>` ?

even if I can just spread an object onto the elements, I'd like to know if there exists something like `cloneElement` but lets you either clone props, or clone the element while changing the type of tag

Answer (score 1):

Well you could define the element type as a string, then use that to build your JSX:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [isMockHeader, setIsMockHeader] = useState(true);
    
    let ElementType = (isMockHeader) ? 'tr' : 'th';

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <ElementType>FooBar</ElementType>
            <br />
            <button onClick={() => setIsMockHeader(p => !p)}>Toggle isMockHeader</button>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```